# What is the right way to create a consumer in Bull NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to make a scheduled job that will send a reminder e-mail after 24h if the receiver hasn't responded yet on the first mail. I want to use Bull to schedule these jobs and so far everything works except it's not sending the e-mails. In fact when it reaches the function it just does nothing, no error no following code nothing.

```
'use strict'
const pool = require('../database')
const Mailer = require('../mailer')

module.exports = async (job) => {
    const query = `SELECT * FROM confirmations WHERE order_id = ${job.data.order_id} AND location_id = ${job.data.location_id}`
    console.log(query)

    const result = await pool.query(query)
    const order = result[0]

    if(!order.has_confirmed){
        console.log('Going to send reminders... ')
        console.log(order.reminders)
        if(order.reminders == 1){
            console.log('sending reminder 1') // This is is reached
            await Mailer.sendConfirmationMail(order.order_id, order.location_id, true, pool, 2)
            // Code placed here is not executed
        }else if(order.reminders == 2){
            const mail = console.log('sending reminder 2')
            await Mailer.sendConfirmationMail(order.order_id, order.location_id, true, pool, 3)

        }else if(order.reminders == 3){
            console.log('sending reminder 3')
            const mail = await Mailer.sendConfirmationMail(order.order_id, order.location_id, true, pool, 4)        

        } 
    }else{
        // if the receiver has confirmed the order the mail should expire without doing anything. 
        console.log('This job is expiring without doing anything...')
    }
}
```

Did I do something wrong? The Mailer.sendConfirmationMail(...) is a bit big but works fine as it sends a mail when called from other parts of my app. Help appreciated!

EDIT:

Mailer is a class which has a couple of functions, basic structure is:

```
class Mailer {
    static async sendConfirmationMail(orderId, locationId, reminder, pool, reminder number){
        console.log('inside Mailer')
        // check some stuff and do a db query
        this.addJobConfirmationQueue(orderId, locationId, reminders, pool)
        // send the email with the right info
    }
    static async addJobConfirmationQueue(orderId, locationId, reminders, pool){
         let day = 10000;
        //const day = 86400000; // milliseconds in a day
        const queue = Bull('checkConfrimation')
        queue.process(processCheckConfirmation)
        const job = await queue.add({
            order_id: order_id,
            location_id: location_id,   
        }, { delay: day })    

        const q =  `UPDATE confirmations
                    SET queue_id = ${pool.escape(job.id)}, reminders = ${pool.escape(reminders + 1)}
                    WHERE order_id = ${pool.escape(order_id)}
                    AND location_id = ${pool.escape(location_id)}`    
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.query(q)
    }
}

module.exports = Mailer
```

Logs I don't really have. I console.log(...) certain phrases so I know it passed a certain point. The chain of console logs are:

1. SQL query
2. 'Going to send reminders'
3. amount of reminders
4. 'sending reminder 1'

Comment: Even when I remove 'await' in front of the Mailer.sendConfirmationMail(...) the code below it will not be executed.

Comment: Could you also provide `sendConfirmationMail`? A minimal working example. And since you have logs, could you also provide the chain of logs that is getting printed before it's stuck?

Comment: Did you try to debug until which exactly line it goes? It probably goes inside the `sendConfirmationMail`. Since we don't see the source code it's impossible to say for sure what's happening there.

Comment: At the start of the sendConfirmationMail(...) is a console.log(...) but it doesn't log when it goes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of different files I fixed it by adding all the code in my Mailer class:

```
static async addJobConfirmationQueue(order_id, location_id, reminders, pool){

        const day = 86400000; // milliseconds in a day
        const queue = new Bull('checkConfirmation')

        queue.process(async (job) => {
            const query = `SELECT * FROM confirmations WHERE order_id = ${job.data.order_id} AND location_id = ${job.data.location_id}`

            const result = await pool.query(query)
            const order = result[0][0]

            if(!order.has_confirmed){
                if(order.reminders == 1){
                    this.sendConfirmationMail(order.order_id, order.location_id, true, pool, 2)

                }else if(order.reminders == 2){
                    this.sendConfirmationMail(order.order_id, order.location_id, true, pool, 3)

                }else if(order.reminders == 3){
                    this.sendConfirmationMail(order.order_id, order.location_id, true, pool, 4)        
                } 
            }else{
                // if the dealer has confirmed the order the mail should expire without doing anything. 
            }
        })
        const job = await queue.add({
            order_id: order_id,
            location_id: location_id,   
        }, { delay: day })    

        const q =  `UPDATE confirmations
                    SET queue_id = ${pool.escape(job.id)}, reminders = ${pool.escape(reminders + 1)}
                    WHERE order_id = ${pool.escape(order_id)}
                    AND location_id = ${pool.escape(location_id)}`    
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.query(q)
    }
```